# Team City problem with unstopped instance of IE during watin test

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, teamcity, watin

We are using Team City and I noticed problem during running Watin test. Sometimes some instance of IE randomly just don't stop in task manager on build server, even if test closes all opened instances. This causes failure of all tests that follows.
We tried with script that kills all instances of ie before this test starts runing, but that can't prevent random unstopped instances of ie that crashes all tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it will help but.... I had a similar error. 
My issue was: "running the tests on Vista with internet explorer having protectedMode = On for localhost "

The solution is documented here:
http://codebetter.com/blogs/james.kovacs/archive/2008/06/18/running-watin-tests-on-vista.aspx

I think you could be having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error message:

> WatiN.Core.Exceptions.TimeoutException
>   : Timeout while Internet Explorer busy
>   TearDown :
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>   : Exception has been thrown by the
>   target of an invocation.
>   ----> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object

.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's related but the timeout issues could be resolved by increasing the timeout as [described in the first comment here](http://16randombytes.blogspot.com/2007/12/watin-testing-aspnet-app-startup-time.html).

> IE.Settings.WaitForCompleteTimeOut

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and solved it by removing the autosave password, it was popping up on the login page and somehow when running inside Teamcity it broke it.